# Dynamic size of collection view cell

Tags: ios, cell, collectionview

I'm trying to set size of collection view cell dynamically:

```
self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(((self.collectionView.bounds.size.width / self.numberOfColumns) - self.itemInsets.left -
                            self.itemInsets.right), ((self.collectionView.bounds.size.width / self.numberOfRows) - self.itemInsets.top - self.itemInsets.bottom));
```

I'm getting following error in logs:

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dcf530 UIImageView:0x14dcf290.leading == UIView:0x14dcf1f0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dcf590 UIView:0x14dcf1f0.trailingMargin == UIImageView:0x14dcf290.trailing>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x14eb4c40 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x14dcf1f0(4)]>"
)
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: I just saw self.interItemSpacingY = 15.0f; can cause the problem, I will try to comment this line firstly and after to include it somehow to my height calculations

Comment: I tried to comment the line with self.interItemSpacingY = 15.0f; and also to include it with minus sign to hight calculation but it didnt help unfortunately, I still cant see any cell in the screen.